# Wordpress: some page_id redirects to latest post — whats wrong?

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have problem with my wordpress site.
For example, my database contains two posts, with ids 10 and 15. When I write:

**/?page_id=10** — I get a redirect to page of my post with id 10, nice.

**/?page_id=20** — I get a redirect to 404 page. Also nice.

**/?page_id=loremimpus** — I get a redirect to the latest post, with ID=15. But I need to redirect to 404 page.

Whats wrong, where is a mistake?

Code of my single.php here:

```html
<?php get_header(); the_post(); ?>

  <article>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  <article>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Try going to permalink settings in your wp-admin, switch it to a different permalink setting, update it, then switch it back to your original setting and update it again.

Comment: @SamJones, it doesn't help. Do you have any other ideas? I suspect that the problems in wp_query...

Comment: Is the page called loremimpus? I thought it was your htaccess but that trick I said usually resets it to wordpresses default. Not really heard of an issue like this! It's usually pages 404'ing when they shouldn't!